# Rails date_select autocomplete attribute birthday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

As per [this document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute) there is a new standard for `autocomplete` attribute to help autocomplete processors.

In the document there is mentioned that one possible `autocomplete` value `bday` or `bday-day`, `bday-month`, `bday-year`.

How can I get this implemented in Rails' [`date_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/date_select) method?

Thanks